# querying add reviewer event timestamps from Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

Is there a way to query the timestamps when reviewers were added to a particular change?

When using Gerrit query, the returned JSON data does not seem to contain this data. Is there any special query parameters for this? I can find timestamps when the reviewers made code-reviews to the changesets from the JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

Apprently, Gerrit does not track the timestamp of when the reviewer was added to the change.

When a reviewer is added to the change, a new row created in `patch_set_approvals` table. Indeed, the `granted` column contains the timestamp of this operation at this point. However, when the reviewer posts the review, the `granted` column is updated with current timestamp again, so the information when he was added to the change is lost.

I believe the value of the `granted` column is what you receives when you use gerrit query.